# My laravel installer just hang when i try to install laravel through composer

Tags: php, laravel, web, composer-php, coding-style

My laravel installer just hang when i try to install laravel through composer.
I have installed the composer.Then i went to the command prompt and type the command 
"composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog"
But it appeared and not doing anything further

Comment: try `composer` command and check whether composer is installed or not

Comment: Have you installed laravel before? sometimes it stuck for me as well but it runs after some time

Comment: no it,s my first time

Comment: @AliKhan Does pressing a space bar in your command line help? (Yes I know my comment is weird)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing composer cache

`composer clearcache`

If still doesn't work
Try using laravel installer for it

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#installing-laravel